# Is it safe to install windows updates on Server 2008 without restarting it?

Tags: update

I've got a windows 2008 production server which I'm planning to install windows updates on, without restarting it for several weeks. 
 Is this a good idea? (This is a production server, which is on continuously, but I'd like to download & install updates now, so that when reboot time comes, I can reboot it right away, without first installing updates.)

Thoughts? ( & Thanks!)

Answer (score -1):

You should be Ok with this. 
Issues may appear after you restart server, once the update is applied.

If this is SP - it's better not to postpone restart and go ahead with restart immediately after installing it.

On the other hand, in opposite situation - I quite often uninstalled patches during business hours and restarted server once I got maintenance window, so that minimizing downtime to only restarting machine.

Comment: Please take a look at the answers on [the linked duplicate](http://serverfault.com/questions/290308/is-delayed-restarting-a-security-issue-after-updating-a-windows-production-webse) -- While you could potentially do what you've been doing for years with no problems, it's certainly not best current practice. Testing updates in your dev environment and then updating production systems with minimal delay between installation & rebooting is far preferable to running in a potentially inconsistent state.